# Jekyll redirect based on date

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages

I have a site that I would consider completely static, and therefore perfectly suited to Jekyll. Roughly this idea:

```
index.md
dir1/day2018-10-25.md
dir1/day2018-10-26.md
...
dir1/day2018-12-31.md
```

Consider that every page works perfectly now. What I want to add is the ability for a user to browse to a url of the form `/today` and have it redirect to `dir1/day2018-10-26` on 26 Oct 2018, but a user browsing to `/today` next month will be directed to the relevant page.

The plug-in jekyll-redirect-from doesn't appear to be the right tool to solve this.  It would let me list `/today` as a redirect in any specified page, but I wouldn't have a way to shift it from one page to the next each day.

I don't know if it's an important consideration, but I'm serving the pages using GitHub Pages (just in case that imposes any additional constraints or gives additional options).

The idea of redirecting differently each day is admittedly a tiny bit dynamic... but it feels like it's so well-defined and pre-defined that it should be achievable. Can Jekyll handle a redirect requirement like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to use javascript redirect :

```
var date = Date.now()
var day = Date.getDate()
var month = Date.getMonth()
var year = Date.getFullYear()
var redirect = "/dir1/day" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + ".md"
windows.location.replace(redirect)
```

You also can do it with a [Jekyll hook plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/hooks/) that will tweak your today.html every days.
The only drawback for this solution is that your site must be build every day in order to update your redirection.

The third solution is to host your site at Netlify and configure redirection with [placeholders](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#placeholders).

Comment: Thanks! As you suggest, javascript redirect is surely simplest. I like it. The Jekyll hook plugin appears interesting. But if I'm reading [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-jekyll-plugins/) correctly, I don't have that option in the context of GitHub Pages. **Placeholders** indeed look elegant if I ever expand beyond using GitHub Pages.